# How to call user32.dll methods from javascript

Tags: javascript, pinvoke, user32

I have a javascript running on a browser. Is it possible to call a function/method in user32.dll.

This is possible from C# by using pInvoke calls. How do I do the same in JavaScript?

Thanks,

Datte

Comment: I'd like to know how to do this in jscript in Internet Explorer with the browser given sufficient permissions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because of the JavaScript sandbox, you can't do it without a middle layer requiring elevated security permissions, such as a Netscape-style browser plug-in (widely supported), ActiveX control (pretty much IE-only), or .Net control (I assume that's possible; again probably IE-only). In each case, the JavaScript would talk to the control, which would in turn make the USER32 call for you.

None of that will work without the user having granted your application elevated permissions, but I'm guessing as you're requiring Windows, this is for some kind of intranet application where that may be possible.

Comment: How could we call user32.dll using ActiveX in jscript?

Comment: @Matthew: Recommend posting your own, new question for that. It's sufficiently different from this question that it's not a duplicate. (And FYI, I don't think it's hard. Write an ActiveX control that exposes a public method that calls into USER32, put the control on the page with an `object` tag, and once the user has allowed it, your JScript code should be able to call the method on the ActiveX control's instance on the page. But I haven't done that in 10+ years, so I'm not the best reed to lean on, I'm sure someone here has recent experience with it.)

Comment: Do you think this would be a good way to do that? http://www.script-coding.com/dynwrapx_eng.html

Answer (score 5):

You definitely need a plug-in, extension or ActiveX of your own installed on the client.

In the case of a firefox extension, you can use [jsctypes](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Jsctypes/api) to wrap the calls easily.
If you use the Jetpack API included with Firefox 4, it will be all JavaScript and won't even require a browser restart.

Here's an exemple from mozilla.org for a basic Hello World :

```
/* Load JS Ctypes Javascript module */
require("chrome").Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm");

/* Load windows api dll */
var lib = ctypes.open("user32.dll");

/* Declare the signature of the function we are going to call */
var msgBox = lib.declare("MessageBoxW",
                         ctypes.stdcall_abi,
                         ctypes.int32_t,
                         ctypes.int32_t,
                         ctypes.ustring,
                         ctypes.ustring,
                         ctypes.int32_t);
var MB_OK = 3;

/* Do it! */
var ret = msgBox(0, "Hello world", "title", MB_OK);

/* Display the returned value */
alert("MessageBox result : "+ret);

lib.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

On the client - it is not possible for security reasons (imagine every site could run system commands on your computer... end of the world - maybe possible with an ActiveX, but that's IE only, but then again, the DLL is windows only).

If you want to run it on the server you'll need to go trough AJAX and C#.

Answer (score 1):

Run dll methods on the client machine using javascript from a web page? That's what is gonna trigger apocalypse.

Comment: [Chrome Extensions](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html) may use DLL's.

Answer (score 0):

If you build your own web browser in C#, you can intercept JavaScript calls and translate them to whatever you want in your browser. Though that won't work if you want it to be available to other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Write a com object that wraps your call to user32.  Invoke it in IE/javascript.
Your DynamicWrapperX object would work for this (it would BE that com object, allowing you to just call your dlls as you wish).