# Call DLL methods from Javascript

Tags: javascript, dll

I want to call a methods of a dll from javascript.

I followed this article [Creating activex objects with c#](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/38890-activex-with-c#/)

Since activeX works in IE only, how should I be able to call those methods from javascript in FireFox or Chrome?

I am already having an application which uses ActiveX object to call Dll Methods, but it works in IE only.

Is there any possible way that will make my application browser Independent?

**UPDATED**

I used Jquery async AJAX and webservice to call dll methods:

```
var to_return = $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "Default.aspx/CallMe", //CallMe is WebService method
         data: "{}", // parameter to pass
         async: false,
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
     });

     alert(to_return.responseText);
```

If **CallMe()** returns a string it is alerting it as **{"d":"True"}** where "True" is the string returned from CallMe.

How will I able to get only returned string from it?

Also, if **CallMe()** method of webservice returns an Object of a class present in that DLL?
How can I retrieve that object in JavaScript?  and
Will I be able to call methods of that class using that returned object?

Please Help.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430619/calling-a-dll-function-from-a-html-page-that-runs-on-chrome-and-firefox?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just execute a dll method in browser (this is done for security reasons). 
 
In order to execute some compiled code in browser you will have to use a [plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649056/how-to-write-a-browser-plugin)

ActiveX is just a method of implementing browser plugin in IE. All other browsers use different plugin interfaces. 
Then if user will install your plugin in browser - this plugin will be available from JS and you can use it to execute some function in dll.

Comment: thanks VitaliyG. Currently I am using this plugin option for now.

Answer (score 3):

something like this should work :

```
var obj = new ActiveXObject("ABCDll.testMethod");
var vResult = obj.TestMethod();
alert(vResult);
```

**:: update ::**

check hazerd's answer from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550112/how-to-call-user32-dll-methods-from-javascript).

Comment: Dear @Nirmal Is it applicable for chrome?
I think ActiveXObject allowed only in IE.