# How can call DLL's in javascript in VS2015

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, dll

I have some DLL files compiled from visual Fortran compiler. How can I call them from javascript client-side (or server-side) .all in visual studio 2015 environment.
any body help me ,brief description or a link or an example will be appreciated.
best regards.

**update 1**: I found some answers as below:

[Call DLL methods from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517319/call-dll-methods-from-javascript)

[Need to call client side DLL from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32548268/need-to-call-client-side-dll-from-browser)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a879e8a0-f1ee-438c-8129-49635d4efe7d/calling-a-function-in-a-dll-from-javascript?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

**update 2**: is it necessary to use javascript call dll (that made from Fortran) or is there anyway else to use Fortran on web?